# How to use Flask API to post two variables via Postman and run a function using them in that call?

Tags: python, api, flask

I have the following function :
`

```
def file(DOCname,TABLEid):
 directory = DOCname
 parent_dir = "E:\\Tables\\Documents\\"+TABLEid
 path = os.path.join(parent_dir, directory)

 try:
      os.makedirs(path, exist_ok = True)
      print("Directory '%s' created successfully" % directory)
 except OSError as error:
      print("Directory '%s' can not be created" % directory)
```

`

Now I want to use a Flask API and call this function to run with two variables that I will provide via Postman, DOCname and TABLEid, but I'm not sure how to run this at the same time I make an API call ?

I tried to run the file under a post request but nothing seems to happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done in following way. The data from the Postman should be send
through the forms .

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import request
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/",methods=["POST"])
def file():
 dic_data = request.form 
 DOCname= dic_data["DOCname"]
 TABLEid = dic_data["TABLEid"]

 directory = DOCname
 parent_dir = "E:\\Tables\\Documents\\"+TABLEid
 path = os.path.join(parent_dir, directory)

 try:
      os.makedirs(path, exist_ok = True)
      print("Directory '%s' created successfully" % directory)
 except OSError as error:
      print("Directory '%s' can not be created" % directory)
```

[image]

Comment: That seems like a really good suggestion but would you happen to know why I get "405 Method Not Allowed" when trying to send form data ?

Comment: Oh nevermind it was casuse I did not define the method like ( methods=['POST']) in app route, it's working now thank you very much !

Answer (score 0):

First you'd need to define your API call. For instance whether you'd be using json. This example assumes json messaging so that the endpoint will accept a POST request and json message of:

```
{ 
  "docname": "mydoc",
  "tableid": "tid0001" 
}
```

If you look at the Flask [quickstart guide](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.2.x/quickstart/):

You can simply make a basic route which takes a POST request like so

```py
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/", methods['POST'])
def endpoint1():
    my_args = request.get_json()
    try:
        success, message = file(my_args["docname"],my_args["tableid"])
    except KeyError:
        success = False
        message = "Invalid arguments"
    return jsonify({"success": success, "msg": message})


def file(DOCname,TABLEid):
   directory = DOCname
   parent_dir = "E:\\Tables\\Documents\\"+TABLEid
   path = os.path.join(parent_dir, directory)

   try:
       os.makedirs(path, exist_ok = True)
       return (True, "Directory '%s' created successfully" % directory)

   except OSError as error:
       return (False, "Directory '%s' can not be created" % directory)
```

and run with `python -m flask --app myscriptname run`

While you can test with postman, you should be able to also demo this with a basic curl command like:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{\
  "docname": "mydoc",\
  "tableid": "tid001"\
}' http://localhost:5000/
```

Comment: The reply above seems to work but I will try this one too to study and learn more, thank you for your valuable input it really helps.